# The meaning of "Wait Start TickCount" and "Ticks" in dump file

Tags: windbg, dump

When I use WinDBG to analyse a kernel model dump file, I can get the information of certain thread. But there are some items that confuse me.

So please help me understand the meaning of the following keywords. Thank you.

1. Wait Start TickCount
2. Ticks
3. UserTime
4. KernelTime

---

Here is one example.

```
    THREAD b6b48908  Cid 1038.10b0  Teb: 7ffac000 Win32Thread: fd517868 WAIT: (WrUserRequest) UserMode Non-Alertable
        b5700630  SynchronizationEvent
    IRP List:
        b6ae6ab8: (0006,01d8) Flags: 00060000  Mdl: 00000000
    Not impersonating
    DeviceMap                 95bd9310
    Owning Process            b5614788       Image:         iexplore.exe
    Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
    Wait Start TickCount      27465609       Ticks: 109779 (0:00:28:32.563)
    Context Switch Count      38627             
    UserTime                  00:00:00.717
    KernelTime                00:00:00.421
    Win32 Start Address 0x6a6439a0
    Stack Init b8b7ded0 Current b8b7d8e0 Base b8b7e000 Limit b8b7b000 Call 0
    Priority 11 BasePriority 8 UnusualBoost 0 ForegroundBoost 2 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
    ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
    b8b7d8f8 8328aefd b6b48908 8333d008 83339e20 nt!KiSwapContext+0x26 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [0,0,4])
    b8b7d930 83289d57 b5700630 b6b48908 b6b489ec nt!KiSwapThread+0x266
    b8b7d958 83285af4 b6b48908 b6b489c8 00000000 nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1df
    b8b7dad4 94bac293 00000001 b8b7db0c 00000001 nt!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x535
    b8b7db44 94bac06c 000025ff 00000000 00000001 win32k!xxxRealSleepThread+0x20b (FPO: [SEH])
    b8b7db60 94ba90b4 000025ff 00000000 00000001 win32k!xxxSleepThread+0x2d (FPO: [3,0,0])
    b8b7dbb8 94bac685 b8b7dbe8 000025ff 00000000 win32k!xxxRealInternalGetMessage+0x4b2 (FPO: [SEH])
    b8b7dc1c 83249dc6 0295c7dc 00000000 00000000 win32k!NtUserGetMessage+0x4d (FPO: [SEH])
    b8b7dc1c 77366bf4 0295c7dc 00000000 00000000 nt!KiSystemServicePostCall (FPO: [0,3] TrapFrame @ b8b7dc34)
    0295c790 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Wait Start TickCount** is the computer internal time representation of when the Thread started waiting, i.e. when it changed from state "running" to state "waiting".

**Ticks** is the difference from Wait Start TickCount to now. These values may affect thread scheduling (together with others, such as the priorities).

**Usertime** is the amount of time the thread had a call stack with user mode functions on top.

**Kerneltime** is the amount of time the thread had a call stack with kernel mode functions on top. This should correspond to the values displayed by `!runaway` in user mode debugging. Both times do not include waiting time, just the actual running time when the thread was really executing CPU instructions.

Comment: Thanks Tomas and Lieven. If a thread is running on processor, its Wait-Start-TickCount will be considered the last time that it started waiting, right?

Comment: @Lucky: yes, so that field will be updated when it starts waiting next time